# How to fit multiple tables into one datagridview

Tags: c#, sqlite, datagridview

Basically I have a c# application which takes values from a textfile, stores them in lists and transfers them into SQLite tables.

The three tables are named abc, t2, and t3 respectively.

I want to then take those sqlite tables and present them in the c# app in datagridviews.
So far I've been been able to transfer 1 table (table abc) to the grid view.
**I want to transfer all 3 tables to the gridview.**

**Problem:** I want to make the 3 tables appear in ONE grid but I simply don't know the syntax on how to do accomplish that.

The following is just how the 3 tables are populated. The more important code (transferring data to grid) is below this

```
    // TRANSFERING VALUES TO THE SQLITE DB

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          // We use these three SQLite objects:
          SQLiteConnection sqlite_conn;
          SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd;
          SQLiteDataReader sqlite_datareader;

          // create a new database connection: // Maybe error here - video was different
          sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=database.db;Version=3;");

          // open the connection:
          sqlite_conn.Open();

          // create a new SQL command:
          sqlite_cmd = sqlite_conn.CreateCommand();

          // Let the SQLiteCommand object know our SQL-Query:
          sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'abc' (Seq text, Field text, Desc text, Len text, Dec text, Typ text, Percnt text, Pop text, Alzero text, MaxLen text );";

          // Now lets execute the SQL                                                                                 
          sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

          // **** SQLITE TRANSFER SECTION 1 - transfer values from list1 to table1 *****

          sqlite_cmd.CommandText = " DELETE FROM abc";
          sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

          sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO abc (Seq, Field, Desc, Len, Dec, Typ, Percnt, Pop, Alzero, MaxLen) VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10)";
          sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", 6);  // dummy initial values 
          sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", 878); 
          sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", 56);
          sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", 6);
          sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", 546);
          sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", 565);
          sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7", 568);
          sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p8", 526);
          sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p9", 586);
          sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p10", 526);


          for (int i = 0; i < NumListValues; i += 10) // Filling SQlite table rows and columns with values from our list 
          {
              sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", list[i]);
              sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", list[i+1]);
              sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", list[i+2]);
              sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", list[i+3]);
              sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", list[i+4]);
              if (i > 490)
                  break; 
              sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", list[i+5]);
              sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7", list[i+6]);
              sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p8", list[i+7]);
              sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p9", list[i+8]);
              sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p10", list[i+9]);
              sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

          }

          //   **** SQLITE TRANSFER SECTION 2 - transfer values from list2 to 2nd table *****

          sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 't2' (YYMM text, MinDate text, MaxDate text, TotalTrans text, DebitTrans text, AMOUNTINDOCUMENTCURREN text );";

          sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

          sqlite_cmd.CommandText = " DELETE FROM t2";
          sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

          sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO t2 (YYMM, MinDate, MaxDate, TotalTrans, DebitTrans, AMOUNTINDOCUMENTCURREN ) VALUES (@b1, @b2, @b3, @b4, @b5, @b6)";
          sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b1", 6);  // dummy initial values 
          sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b2", 878); 
          sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b3", 56);
          sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b4", 6);
          sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b5", 546);
          sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b6", 565);

         for (int i = 0; i < NumList2Values; i+= 6) // Filling SQlite table rows and columns with values from list2
         {
             sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b1", list2[i]);
             sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b2", list2[i+1]);
             sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b3", list2[i+2]);
             sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b4", list2[i+3]);
             sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b5", list2[i+4]);
             sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b6", list2[i+5]);
             sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }



        // Create table to transfer values from list 3

       sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 't3' (YYWW text, MinDate text, MaxDate text, TotalTrans text, DebitTrans text, AMOUNTINDOCUMENTCURREN text );";

       sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

       sqlite_cmd.CommandText = " DELETE FROM t3";
       sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

       sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO t3 (YYWW, MinDate, MaxDate, TotalTrans, DebitTrans, AMOUNTINDOCUMENTCURREN ) VALUES (@c1, @c2, @c3, @c4, @c5, @c6)";
       sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c1", 6);  // dummy initial values 
       sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c2", 878); 
       sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c3", 56);
       sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c4", 6);
       sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c5", 546);
       sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c6", 565);

       for (int i = 0; i < NumList3Values ; i+= 6) // Filling SQlite table rows and columns with values from list2
       {
           sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c1", list3[i]);
           sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c2", list3[i+1]);
           sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c3", list3[i+2]);
           sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c4", list3[i+3]);
           sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c5", list3[i+4]);
           sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c6", list3[i+5]);
           sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

       }
```

**The following is how I populate the datagrid with values from the first table**

```
       string sql = " SELECT * FROM abc";
       SQLiteDataAdapter da;
       DataTable dt;

       sqlite_cmd.CommandText = sql;

       //Create New Datatable to fill with data
       dt = new DataTable();

       //Create DataAdapter to fill data in DataTable via Adapter
       da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, sqlite_conn);
       da.Fill(dt);

       // Lets populate the datagrid
       dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
       dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataGridView` can only deal with one table and thus you have to combine all your tables into a single one. You have various options to do this and also depends upon how you want to perform the merging exactly. Sample code:

```
DataTable allDTs = abc;
int rowCount = allDTs.Rows.Count - 1;
foreach (DataRow row in t2.Rows)
{
    rowCount = rowCount + 1;
    allDTs.Rows.Add();

    int colCount = -1;
    foreach (DataColumn col in t2.Columns)
    {
        colCount = colCount + 1;
        if (colCount > allDTs.Columns.Count - 1) allDTs.Columns.Add(col.ColumnName);
        allDTs.Rows[rowCount][colCount] = row[col];
    }
}

rowCount = allDTs.Rows.Count - 1;
foreach (DataRow row in t3.Rows)
{
    rowCount = rowCount + 1;
    allDTs.Rows.Add();

    int colCount = -1;
    foreach (DataColumn col in t3.Columns)
    {
        colCount = colCount + 1;
        if (colCount > allDTs.Columns.Count - 1) allDTs.Columns.Add(col.ColumnName);
        allDTs.Rows[rowCount][colCount] = row[col];
    }
}

dataGridView1.DataSource = allDTs;
```

This code comes from the assumption that you want to put all the columns of each `DataTable` one after the other (all the `abc` columns, then `t2`/`t3` ones); but the algorithm is quite clear and you shouldn't find any problem to adapt it to your specific needs.

Comment: This is very insightful, I'll try it out but my assumption was that after table 1 is done, then I want t2 inserted BELOW it, not all columns beside.

Comment: @vacrocarbas Forgot to tag

Comment: (it is varocarbas, but you don't need to it in my own answer) OK, I will change the code, although you should do it by your own...

Comment: Appreciate it, I'm a new programmer so I was having a difficult time.

Comment: @user7068 No problem. There you have it. Bear in mind that this code can deal with DataTables with different number of columns/rows.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this depends on how you wish to format the data that you are trying to display. I assume you want something like [abc-col1][abc-col2][t2-col1] ...[t3-col3]

A quick and dirty way to do this would be to use the a 'datarow' and combine the data as you see it fit into a new datatable;

```
datatable combinetable = new datatable();

for (i=0;i<abc.rows.count;i++)
{
for (j=0;j<abc.columns.count;j++)
{
datarow newdatarow = new datarow();
newdatarow[j] = abc[i,j];



}
 combinetable.rows.add(newdatarow);
}


for (i=0;i<t2.rows.count;i++)
{
for (j=0;j<t2.columns.count;j++)
{
datarow newdatarow = new datarow();
newdatarow[j] = t2[i,j];



}
combinetable.rows.add(newdatarow);
}
```

just replace the [i,j] parts with the indexes of the actual values you want to combine, and you are done! you may need to add another loop if you have multiple columns per datatable, which i presume you do. After you have made the new combined datatable, just set that to the datagridview source like you did above.

Hope that helps. Cheers.

Comment: I want table1, then after all of the table1 values are finished, BELOW the table, i want to insert table t2, not side by side. I will try to understand your post, thanks!

Comment: that is actually even easier, basically just make one loop add datarows until the end of one table, then do another loop for the next table and so on.

    for (i...abc.rows.count)   
    {   
      for (j...abc.columns.count)
        {
     datarow newdatarow = new datarow();   
     newdatarow[j] = abc[i,j];   

}
}

AGAIN with abc replaced with t2   
AGAIN with abc replaced with t3.   
   
Hard to see with formatting but i tried to leave spaces

Comment: I am afraid that this code is wrong (i.e., does not fulfil OP's requirements): you are adding as many rows as rows times columns. You have to put the Rows.Add bit in the rows loop (outside the columns one). Also you should account for the eventuality that not all the DataTables have the same number of columns (and add further columns if required).

Comment: Good catch thanks! i changed the answer to move the adddatarow outside the j-loop. Haste makes waste. Also, i just assumed that the user should add the columns before the loops anyways or else it wouldn't work in the first place.